# Responsive canvas size and iText rendering with fabricJS

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabricjs in my responsive webpage. I am trying to add some text to the canvas. So far this works ok.

Because the webpage is responsive, the canvas container changes in size according to the viewport. I would like that the canvas always takes 90% of the container element. Therefore I am scaling the canvas and all elements inside it so that they keep the same relative positions but take the 90% of the container. ( -> Is there any better way to do this?)

Everything works ok, except for the text rendering when the canvas loads for the first time. The text elements seem to be streetched. Other elements (Rect, Graphic) are added ok.

[image: ERROR in iText display]

This is how it should look like. And when I click on the canvas or enable developers tools of a browser, the iText elements get rendered to the correct size.

[image: Text displayed ok]

I have tried using object.setCoords() on iText object and also canvas.calcOffset() which is suggested in many posts that I've come accross, but unfortunately with no success.

And by iText element I also have a problem with the cursor position - when I click on the element and try to edit it's content, the coursor is not displayed in between the characters (where would normaly be) but on the caracters.

[image: Wrong cursor position]

Did somebody else come across this problem? What are your techniques in using fabricjs in responsive design, when the size of a canvas container changes?

Comment: Not familiar with this exact library, but I do know that when it comes to canvas sizing, you can't do it all in CSS - like developing a video game and changing resolution in a menu, there will be numerous pixel-related variables/calculations you are writing yourself (or that fabricjs is doing) that will need to update to take into account the new sizing. So, unlike most element types where their form of appearance is static, it somewhat makes sense that it needs you to write some form of "onresize" method yourself for canvases.

Comment: This is certainly a font issue. Your CSS or other styling is conflicting and causing a different font in the initial state. If you look at both the images, the text is not shrunken in size...rather it is having entirely different font.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
@Katana314: I'm not using css to resize the canvas and it's elements. I do it with js, with manipulating the fabricJS canvas elements.

Comment: @Vijay: I have checked the font-family right after the canvas is rendered (when the problem occurs) and after the text gets rendered ok. In both cases is the font-family the same - "ubuntumedium", "Helvetica Neue", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif. Therefore the font-family could not be the problem.

Comment: @knospe: did you checked it in firebug css pane or programmatically?

Comment: @Vijay: This is how my canvas tag looks like:

<code>
<canvas id="c" class="lower-canvas" width="563" height="563" style="position: absolute; width: 563px; height: 563px; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-user-select: none;"></canvas>
</code>

"width" and "height" get changed, when the viewport changes.

I've just found out, that the cursors position is right, when the other font-family is used. When font-family is "sanelma", "Helvetica Neue", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif, than the cursor is positioned ok.

Comment: @knospe: could you please add a live sample or fiddle....would like to play with this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69657/discussion-between-vijay-and-knospe).

Answer (score 2):

To solve the problem with the cursor position, we disable cache for iText object.

When set to false, this disables (character width) caching for iText object.